# Jquery DataTable does not reload

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Here is the flow,
User clicks submit, Based on his selections, a datatable get populated.
He changes something on the form, this data table should get updated.
Note: The number of columns may vary with subsequent submits.

```
var bk_dataset = []

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  url: "/booking-granular/callback-from-js-bk",
  data: postData

}).done(function(data) {
  bk_dataset = data.query_res;
  $('#bk_grid').DataTable({
    destroy: true,
    data: bk_dataset,
    columns: titleArray
  });
  $('#bk_showquery').text(data.query);
  document.getElementById('bk_mailButton').classList.remove("mailbutton");
  document.getElementById('bk_loader_image').classList.add("onload");
  document.getElementById('bk_loader_image').classList.remove("onshow");
  $("#bk_granular_tab").find("*").prop("disabled", false);

}).fail(function(xhr, result, status) {
  alert('GetPermissions ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText + ' ' + xhr.status);
});
```

bk_dataset and titleArray are pre-populated arrays that are created dynamically on the submit request.
It works perfectly when I load the Datatable first time.

Problem is , when I make a second ajax call with more columns than last time, it errors with :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

I have tried several solutions but nothing works. 
I believe it has something to do with the number of columns ,because when I submit with the same number of columns as before,  it works.

Comment: Is the number of columns also dynamic? Can you share `titleArray` data?

Comment: Yes the number of columns is dynamic.

This is the array on the first call:

{title: "WaivedForUser", sTitle: "WaivedForUser"}
length
:
1


And this on second call:

0
:
{title: "WaivedForUser", sTitle: "WaivedForUser"}
1
:
{title: "UserId", sTitle: "UserId"}
length
:
2

Comment: This usually happens when the number of `th` in HTML table is not same as the number of columns mentioned in DataTable. You need to update the no. of `th` based on `titleArray` length.

Comment: Yes, I have read this at several places. But I don't have any <th> at all. My columns and data are both coming from arrays. I think datatable does all of the html on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I know this case from David is old but it's just happened with me this week using a CDN version of Datatables, I made a simple solution, the idea is to remove and create the  every time, like this:

HTML

```
<div id="table">
   <table id="example" class="table"></table>
   <div id="example_wrapper" class="table"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function delete_table() {
   var table = document.getElementById("example");
   if (table) table.remove();
   var table_w = document.getElementById("example_wrapper");
   if (table_w) table_w.remove();
}

function create_table() {
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("id", "example");
    table.setAttribute("class", "table table-striped");
    var id = document.getElementById("table");
    id.appendChild(table);
  }

function draw_table(data) {
   delete_table();
   create_table();

   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#example').dataTable({
         "sorting": false,
         "searching": false,
         "paging": false,
         "info": false,
         "data": data.data,
         "columns": data.columns
      });
   });
}
```

The  example-wrapper has also to be destroyed otherwise every time you remove a table it will remains in the document, so for saving memory it's nice the remove it. This can handle dynamic table with different number of columns.